# python out of stack, how to allocate more?

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a python script that does os.system('cscript blabla.js unittest'), it runs unit test. the tests runs from the commandline, but python gives me out of stack space (ironpython actually), is there any way to allocate more stack space to python?

Unit Tests Suite
   TEST MODULE: Uize.Test.Uize
      REQUIRE TEST MODULE: Uize.Test.Uize

---

TIME STARTED: Fri Jul 11 11:53:43 PDT 2014
TIME ENDED: Fri Jul 11 11:53:43 PDT 2014
DURATION: 8ms

---

REASON FOR FAILURE...

JavaScript Error...
ERROR NAME: Error
ERROR MESSAGE: Out of stack space
ERROR DESCRIPTION: Out of stack space
LINE NUMBER: -2146828260
STACK TRACE: undefined

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: i guess the exact error message is not very useful in this case

Comment: How are your running out of stack space? Are you using recursion?

Comment: os.system('cscript blabla.js unittest') is the command that runs outta stack, i have no idea what they do in blabla.js

Comment: Well there is no way for *we* to know what they do in `blabla.js` if *you* don't.